# Weird noise from front right tire

Tags: dodge, noise, durango

I just got my old 1999 Dodge Durango running again and there seems to be this sound coming from the front right tire when I lean to the right in any sort of way. We just got done replacing the whole brake system and went to drive it and I started hear the slightly embarrassing noise, any idea what it could be? (Mixture of clicking and squealing)

Comment: Record a video/audio of it and post back as an edit to your question. Also post details of what was done to the brakes, also as an edit.

Comment: You said you got it running again. How long was it sitting? Also, did you do the brakes before or after it was sitting? I suggest going back thru the brake system to make sure you didn't inadvertently put something together wrong. Also, check the backing plate. One time I accidentally leaned on one enough that it barley rubbed causing noise when all assembled.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have just performed maintenance on the wheel, there are 3 items you should check immediately

1. The mounting of the brake caliper. Is the caliper bracket secured properly? Is it installed in the correct orientation (some can actually be installed upside down). Is the caliper properly fastened to the brackets? Can it move on the caliper slide pins?
2. The orientation of the brake pads. It is very to install brake pads backwards or wind up with both pads on the same side of the rotor. The caliper should have a window that allows viewing the pads. The friction material on the pad should only contact the rotor. The backer pad should only contact the caliper. If the brake pads use anti squeal shims (thin pieces of metal) verify that they have not moved and are not contacting any rotating parts
3. The wheel bearing. On some vehicles, repacking of the wheel bearing is normal and expected as part of brake maintenance. In any case, it should be checked. This can be done by simply jacking up the vehicle and rotating the tire. It should rotate smoothly when spun by hand, although the brake pads normally cause a small amount of drag. The wheel should not move independently of the vehicle's suspension. If it does, the wheel bearing may be failing. If there is even a suspicion of wheel bearing failure, the assembly should be taken apart and a visual inspection performed.

Also important: is the vehicle 4 wheel drive? The front axle of a 4WD truck is usually nothing like the 2WD version. There are many more moving parts that could be the issue.